d3js pie chart with specific less traditional different patterns for the segments with slightly rounded corners
I am experimenting with different styles for charts - and I am wondering how to create these exact kind of pattern textures charts for the different segments.

How do you start creating some of these specific patterns if its something less traditional like a big/small dot tessellation.

Or if there is a gradient instead of a pattern

and in this case there appears to be a slight rounding at the edges of the pie as if it were stacked on top of each other and overlayed more.
d3js pie chart with different patterns for the segments

demo reference with a legend on the left - and pie/half pie on the right

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-wiles-forked-fvj79p
my current build -- regular pie
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './PieChart1.scss';

class PieChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            theme: this.props.theme ? this.props.theme : ['#bde0fe', '#2698f9', '#71bcfd', '#f1f8fe']
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var $this = this.myRef.current;

        d3.select($this)
            .selectAll('svg')
            .remove();

        const data = this.props.data;

        const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
            height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
            radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
            innerradius = parseInt(this.props.ir, 10);

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme);

        var arc = d3
            .arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(innerradius);

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.total = +d.value;
        });

        var pie = d3
            .pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
                return d.total;
            });

        var svg = d3
            .select($this)
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'piechart')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');

        var slices = segments
            .selectAll('.arc')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc');

        slices
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .transition()
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
                return function(t) {
                    d.endAngle = i(t);
                    return arc(d);
                }
            });

    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.myRef} className="PieChart" />;
    }
}
export default PieChart;

I've seen this example in making a pattern - how would you make these 4 pattern types -- one appears to be just a gradient


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        // SVG injection:
var svg = d3.select("#hook").append("svg").attr("id", "d3svg")
    .attr("width", 120)
    .attr("height", 120);
//Pattern injection
var defs = svg.append("defs")
var pattern = defs.append("pattern")
        .attr({ id:"hash4_4", width:"8", height:"8", patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse", patternTransform:"rotate(-45)"})
    .append("rect")
        .attr({ width:"4", height:"8", transform:"translate(0,0)", fill:"#88AAEE" });

//Shape design
svg.append("g").attr("id","shape")
    .append("circle")
.attr({cx:"60",cy:"60",r:"50", fill:"url(#hash4_4)" })
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Found this as a reference -- but not sure how to make those exact patterns in the demo
How to make the patterns of a pie chart parallel to the center line of sectors in d3.js?


<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.15.1/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg id="pie" width="300" height="200"> </svg>
<svg id="legend">
    
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern0);" />   
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />   
        <rect x="200" y="0" width="100" height="100"
        style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern2);" />   
</svg>

<script>
    var data = [{ year: '2001', value:10 },
            { year: '2002', value:30 },
            { year: '2003', value:60 },
           ]

    var svg = d3.select("svg#pie"),
        width = svg.attr("width"),
        height = svg.attr("height"),
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(['#4daf4a','#377eb8','#ff7f00','#984ea3','#e41a1c']);

    // Generate the pie
    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) { 
    return d.value;})(data);

    // Generate the patterns
    var legend = d3.select("svg#legend"),
        defs = legend.append("defs");
    defs.selectAll("pattern")
        .data(pie)
        .enter()
        .append("pattern")
        .attr("id", (d, i) => "pattern" + i)
        .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("patternTransform", (d) => `rotate(${(d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI})`)
        .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
             .append("rect")
             .attr("x", 5)
             .attr("y", 5)
             .attr("width", 10)
             .attr("height", 10)

    // Generate the arcs
    var arc = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(0)
                .outerRadius(radius);

    //Generate groups
    var arcs = g.selectAll("arc")
                .data(pie)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc")

    //Draw arc paths
    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
  .attr('stroke', "black")
            .attr('stroke-width', '1')
            .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return  "url(#pattern" + i +")"});
</script>
</script>



19th Sep - latest version - with general patterns - but not the ones we need or legend in the right place.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-wiles-forked-pmdgrs
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "./PieChart1.scss";

class PieChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      theme: this.props.theme
        ? this.props.theme
        : ["#bde0fe", "#2698f9", "#71bcfd", "#f1f8fe"],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var $this = this.myRef.current;

    d3.select($this).selectAll("svg").remove();

    const data = this.props.data;

    const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
      height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
      radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
      innerradius = parseInt(this.props.ir, 10);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme);

    var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius).innerRadius(innerradius);

    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.total = +d.value;
    });

    var pie = d3
      .pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function (d) {
        return d.total;
      });

    var svg = d3
      .select($this)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "piechart")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    // Generate the patterns
    var legend = d3.select("svg#legend"),
      defs = legend.append("defs");
    defs
      .selectAll("pattern")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("pattern")
      .attr("id", (d, i) => "pattern" + i)
      .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr(
        "patternTransform",
        (d) => `rotate(${((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90) / Math.PI})`
      )
      .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 5)
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10);

    var segments = svg.append("g").attr("class", "segments");

    var slices = segments
      .selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    slices
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      //.attr("fill", function (d, i) {
      //  return color(i);
      //})
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", "1")
      .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return "url(#pattern" + i + ")";
      })
      .transition()
      .attrTween("d", function (d) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
        return function (t) {
          d.endAngle = i(t);
          return arc(d);
        };
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <svg id="legend">
          <rect
            x="0"
            y="0"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            style={{ stroke: "#000000", fill: "url(#pattern0)" }}
          />
          <rect
            x="100"
            y="0"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            style={{ stroke: "#000000", fill: "url(#pattern1)" }}
          />
          <rect
            x="200"
            y="0"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            style={{ stroke: "#000000", fill: "url(#pattern2)" }}
          />
        </svg>

        <div ref={this.myRef} className="PieChart" />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default PieChart;


Could start out by generating a pattern maker
basic patterns first

circles only

https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/aWZdXP   -- just markup
we would need to remake the svg in js
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  
  <!-- Create mask that we'll use to define a slight gradient -->
  <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="fade">
    <!-- Here's that slight gradient -->
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset ="0" style="stop-color: #FFFFFF" />
      <stop offset ="1" style="stop-color: #000000" />
    </linearGradient>
    <!-- The canvas for our mask -->
    <rect fill="url(#gradient)" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </mask>
    
  <!-- Let's define the pattern -->
  <!-- The width and height should be double the circle radius we plan to use -->
  <pattern id="pattern-circles" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <!-- Now let's draw the circle -->
    <!-- We're going to define the `fill` in the CSS for flexible use -->
    <circle mask="url(#fade)" cx="20" cy="20" r="20" />
  </pattern>
  <!-- The canvas with our applied pattern -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-circles)" />
  
</svg>



// create svg element:
var svg = d3.select("#circle").append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200)

// Add the path using this helper function
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 100)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('fill', '#69a3b2');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="circle"></div>




squares only

https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/KmgxxN -- just markup
we would need to remake the svg in js
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    
  <!-- Let's define the pattern -->
  <!-- The width and height should be double the size of a single checker -->
  <pattern id="pattern-checkers" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
    <!-- Two instances of the same checker, only positioned apart on the `x` and `y` axis -->
    <!-- We will define the `fill` in the CSS for flexible use -->
    <rect class="checker" x="0" width="100" height="100" y="0"/>
    <rect class="checker" x="100" width="100" height="100" y="100"/>
  </pattern>
  
  <!-- Define the shape that will contain our pattern as the fill -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-checkers)" />
  
</svg>



// create svg element:
var svg = d3.select("#rect").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 200)

// Add the path using this helper function
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 120)
  .attr('width', 40)
  .attr('height', 40)
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('fill', '#69a3b2');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="rect"></div>




honeycomb only

https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/oWLLvZ -- just markup
we would need to remake the svg in js
<svg width="100%" height="100%" >
   
    <!-- Define the pattern -->
    <pattern id="pattern-hex" x="0" y="0" width="112" height="190" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="56 -254 112 190">
        
      <!-- Group the hexagon shapes -->
      <!-- Each path could have a class for more styling/animating options -->
      <!-- We're going to control the fill and stroke in the CSS for flexibility -->
      <g id="hexagon">
            <path d="M168-127.1c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3,0.3l53.4,30.5c0.7,0.4,1.3,1.4,1.3,2.2v61c0,0.8-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.2L169.3-0.3
            c-0.7,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.6,0l-53.4-30.5c-0.7-0.4-1.3-1.4-1.3-2.2v-61c0-0.8,0.6-1.8,1.3-2.2l53.4-30.5C167-127,167.5-127.1,168-127.1
            L168-127.1z"/>
          <path d="M112-222.5c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3,0.3l53.4,30.5c0.7,0.4,1.3,1.4,1.3,2.2v61c0,0.8-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.2l-53.4,30.5
            c-0.7,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.6,0l-53.4-30.5c-0.7-0.4-1.3-1.4-1.3-2.2v-61c0-0.8,0.6-1.8,1.3-2.2l53.4-30.5
            C111-222.4,111.5-222.5,112-222.5L112-222.5z"/>
          <path d="M168-317.8c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3,0.3l53.4,30.5c0.7,0.4,1.3,1.4,1.3,2.2v61c0,0.8-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.2L169.3-191
            c-0.7,0.4-1.9,0.4-2.6,0l-53.4-30.5c-0.7-0.4-1.3-1.4-1.3-2.2v-61c0-0.8,0.6-1.8,1.3-2.2l53.4-30.5
            C167-317.7,167.5-317.8,168-317.8L168-317.8z"/>
      </g>
  
  </pattern>
   
  <!-- The canvas for our pattern -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-hex)" />
  
</svg>


cubes only

https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/YVWqxG -- just markup
we would need to remake the svg in js
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
   
   <!-- Define the pattern -->
   <pattern id="pattern-cubes" x="0" y="126" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="126" height="200" viewBox="0 0 10 16"> 
     
     <!-- Cube code courtest of SVGeneration: http://www.svgeneration.com/recipes/3D-Cubes/ -->
     <g id="cube">
       <!-- We'll apply the `fill` in the CSS for flexibility -->
       <path class="left-shade" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z" />
       <path class="right-shade" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3" />
     </g>
    
     <!-- Apply the cube shapes -->
     <use x="5" y="8" xlink:href="#cube" />
     <use x="-5" y="8" xlink:href="#cube" />
   
   </pattern>
   
   <!-- The canvas for our pattern -->
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-cubes)" />
  
</svg>


wiggle lines

https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/xdOVjG -- just markup
we would need to remake the svg in js
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
   
   <!-- Define the pattern -->
   <pattern id="pattern-chevron" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="180" viewBox="0 0 10 18"> 
     
     <!-- Group the chevron shapes -->
     <g id="chevron">
       <!-- Chevron consists of two shapes, a left and a right to form a `v` -->
       <!-- We'll apply the `fill` in the CSS for flexibility -->
       <path class="left" d="M0 0l5 3v5l-5 -3z" />
       <path class="right" d="M10 0l-5 3v5l5 -3" />
     </g>
    
     <!-- Apply the shapes -->
     <!-- `y="9"` narrows the space between rows  -->
     <use x="0" y="9" xlink:href="#chevron" />
   
   </pattern>
   
   <!-- The canvas for our pattern -->
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-chevron)" />
  
</svg>


arcs

<path style="fill: #69b3a2" stroke="black" transform="translate(400,200)" d="M0,149 A150,150,0,0,1,-0.47,-149.9 L-0.3,-99.9 A100,100,0,0,0,0.15,99.9Z"></path>



// create svg element
var svg = d3.select("#arc").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 400)

// add an arc
svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(400,200)")
  .attr("d", d3.arc()
    .innerRadius( 100 )
    .outerRadius( 150 )
    .startAngle( 3.14 )     // It's in radian, so Pi = 3.14 = bottom.
    .endAngle( 6.28 )       // 2*Pi = 6.28 = top
    )
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('fill', '#69b3a2');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="arc"></div>




line maker

p = "M10,60L40,90L60,10L190,10"
p = d3.line()([[10, 60], [40, 90], [60, 10], [190, 10]])



const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 600]) // 600 is our chart width
 
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([400, 0]) // 400 is our chart height


const line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.x))
  .y(d => yScale(d.y))
  .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(.5))


d3.select('#lines')
  .append('path') // add a path to the existing svg
  .datum([
    { x: 0,   y: 20 },
    { x: 20,  y: 20 },
    { x: 40,  y: 40 },
    { x: 60,  y: 30 },
    { x: 80,  y: 40 },
    { x: 100, y: 30 },
  ])
  .attr('d', line)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div ><svg id="lines" width="600" height="400"></svg></div>




dot maker

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/MYmbwv
we would need to remake the svg in js
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  
  <pattern id="pattern-circles" 
           x="0" 
           y="0" 
           width="20" 
           height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <circle id="pattern-circle" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill= "#f06d06" />
  </pattern>
  
  <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-circles)" />
  
</svg>


https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/svg-pattern-guide/
